# Unit in Principal Ideal Domain

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

So I have a statement that say "Let D be a principal ideal domain, if a is unit then (a)=D". How it could be? I don't understand, can anyone explains it to me? Thank you.

Comment: That is because as $a$ is a unit the ideal generated by $a$ contains $1$, hence all multiples of $1$. It is actually true for any unital ring.

Comment: Because for any given $x$, $x=xa^{-1}\cdot a\in (a)$

Comment: This is true for any ring, not just PID's. An ideal $I$ is the entire ring if and only if $I$ contains a unit.

Comment: Okay, I understand all of your explanation. Thank you guys.